# What is the MAXIMUM number of variables that can be entered into an SPSS Frequencies command?

Tags: spss

As it says on the tin. I know that it will be somewhere between 125 and 2013 but trying to streamline my code.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DOCS say 1000 is the maximum](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.statistics.help%2Fsyn_frequencies_overview.htm) (see the Limitations section). You could reach the limits of displaying tables in the output in memory, making the effective number smaller (depends on the style of tables you have it output as well as the number of rows displayed in the tables).

This isn't to say that outputting 1,000 frequencies is ever a really good idea. Why would you ever want to visually pour over that many tables?

Comment: I have 25k variables and want to check the min and max of each of them. I output to Excel and manipulate using filtering to judge which vars are the ones I want to keep. Seeing as I can't put 25k vars in a 1 freq then it means I have to copy all the output and then start deleting the logs and notes in between. Fun but worth it.

Comment: See the `AGGREGATE` command @user3032288. A much simpler way and will return the data in an easier environment to work with. I would probably reshape the date using `VARSTOCASES`, save the variable names in a column and then use one `AGGREGATE` command to get the min and max per variable.

Comment: Good point. Not thought of that, ridiculously! Then save as Excel if required. Nice. Thanks for the help